# Dual space of $L^2(0,T;H^1) + L^p(0,T;L^p)$ and its duality pairing?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V=L^2(0,T;H^1) + L^p(0,T;L^p)$. We know that its dual space is $V^* = L^2(0,T;H^{-1}) \cap L^p(0,T;L^p)$.

So if $v \in V$, then by definition $v=a+b$ where $a \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ and $b \in L^p(0,T;L^p)$.

My question is, given $f \in V^*$, what does a duality pairing
$$\langle f, v \rangle_{V^*, V}$$ look like? Is it composed of the duality pairings of $L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ and $L^{p'}(0,T;L^{p'})$ in some way? How to think of it intuitively?

If $p =2$, then isn't $V^*=L^2(0,T;L^2)$? But then the dual of $V^*$, which should be $V$, is $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ too, but this is not the same space as $L^2(0,T;H^1) + L^2(0,T;L^2)$!!

Comment: Yes, if $p=2$ then we do have $L^2(0,T;H^1) + L^2(0,T;L^2) = L^2(0,T;L^2)$ since $H^1$ is a subspace of $L^2$.